# Generating a table of gradients

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some function (say, $f(x,y)=x^2+y$) I want to take the gradient of. I then want to make a table of $|\nabla f|$ evaluated at different values of $x$ and $y$. Here's the code I wrote:

```
Table[Norm[Grad[x^2+y,{x,y}]],{x,1,10},{y,1,10}]
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Grad::nocoord: {1,1} is not a non-empty list of valid variables. $\gg$
>
> Grad::nocoord: {1,2} is not a non-empty list of valid variables. $\gg$
>
> Grad::nocoord: {1,3} is not a non-empty list of valid variables. $\gg$
>
> General::stop: Further output of Grad::nocoord will be suppressed during this calculation. $\gg$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Table[Evaluate[Norm[Grad[x^2 + y, {x, y}]]], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]`?

Comment: That works! Can you please post it as a reply so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[Evaluate[Norm[Grad[x^2 + y, {x, y}]]], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
```

or

```
Table[Norm[Grad[x^2 + y, {x, y}]] /. {x -> u, y -> v}, {u, 1, 10}, {v, 1, 10}]
```

both give (when wrapped with `TeXForm`):

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} \\
>  \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} & \sqrt{17} \\
>  \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} & \sqrt{37} \\
>  \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} & \sqrt{65} \\
>  \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101} & \sqrt{101}
>    \\
>  \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145} & \sqrt{145}
>    \\
>  \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197} & \sqrt{197}
>    \\
>  \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257} & \sqrt{257}
>    \\
>  5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5 \sqrt{13} & 5
>    \sqrt{13} \\
>  \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401} & \sqrt{401}
>    \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks! The first option is more concise, but I suppose the second one better illustrates what exactly you're doing to avoid the problem.

Comment: @Rain, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.